# Parse error when running script in Automation Instrument Ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad, testing, ios-ui-automation

I am trying to use Automation Instrument on Ipad. But I keep getting the following error for my javascript:
Exception raised while running script: SyntaxError: Parse error

It would be really helpful if someone could help me solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well it seems you have error in your code. You need to provide the code, so people can look a it. Best would be to provide whole JS code, and Instruments output, where it says details of error (error type, and line where it happens).

Comment: Also note that if you open the "Detail" (far right) panel in Instruments and highlight the line reporting the parse error the Detail panel usually tells you where the error is (on or about) in the JavaScript.